# questions about using pymongo to insert date and time into mongo

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime, pymongo

I want to insert date and time into mongo ,using pymongo.

However, I can insert datetime but not just date or time .

here is the example code :

now = datetime.datetime.now()

log_date = now.date()

log_time = now.time()

self.logs['test'].insert({'log_date_time': now, 'log_date':log_date, 'log_time':log_time})

it show errors :

bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: datetime.time(9, 12, 39, 535769)

in fact , i don't know how to insert just date or time in mongo shell  too.

i  know insert datetime is new Date(), but I just want the date or time filed.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing the defined behavior.  MongoDB has a single datetime type (datetime).   There are no separate, discrete types of just date or just time.

Workarounds:  Plenty, but food for thought:
Storing just date is straightforward:  assume Z time, use a time component of 00:00:00, and ignore the time offset upon retrieval.
Storing just time is trickier but doable:  establish a base date like the epoch and only vary the time component, and ignore the date component upon retrieval.